# Successive setTimout() calls all execute at once

Tags: javascript

```
setTimeout(thisFunc, 500);
setTimeout(thatFunc, 500);
setTimeout(otherFunc, 500);
finalFunc();
```

What I expect is thisFunc(), followed by a half second pause, then thatFunc() followed by a half second pause, then otherFunc(), followed by a pause.  Then finalFunc().

What actually happens, is the page pauses for 1 1/2 seconds then all four functions seem to execute at once.

How can I achieve the pause I am after?  It's being done purely for aesthetical purposes in the UI.

Comment: Of course they do. `setTimeout` doesn't block for 500ms. It runs `thisFunc` after 500ms. If you really want to chain them, then you need to have the callback `thisFunc` set the timeout for the next function and so on. Or fudge it by setting the delays to different values. Which is better depends on exactly what you are trying to do and whether it's more important when they start, or if the spacing between them is more important

Comment: Those calls are asynchronous, if you want one to happen after the other you should nest them in the callbacks

Comment: Actually, `finalFunc()` runs first, then 500ms later `thisFunc()` runs, then immediately `thatFunc()` runs and then `otherFunc()` runs right after that.  `setTimeout()` does not block.  It merely schedules a function to run some time in the future and then other JS right after it continues to run.  It's like putting an event in your calendar with a reminder.  You will get notified in the future, but the rest of your life continues just fine until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give the `delay` properly,

```
setTimeout(thisFunc, 500);
setTimeout(thatFunc, 1000);
setTimeout(otherFunc, 1500);
setTimeout(finalFunc, 2000);
```

If you give `500` ms for all the `setTimeout`s, then every thing would be fired at a same time.

And the best approach would be,

```
var func = function(func){ func(); }

function setContinuos() {
  var funcs = Array.from(arguments);
  var delay = funcs.pop();
  funcs.forEach(function(itm, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      func(itm);
    }, (index + 1) * delay)
  });
}

setContinuos(func1,func2,func3,func4,500);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lthns5md/)

Comment: This will execute `finalFunc()` first.  Use: `setTimeout(finalFunc, 2000);`

Comment: @J.V.A. Thanks for pointing that. Just now read that in OP's requirement.

Comment: I swear, javascript's async bug bites me at least once a week.  ;-)  I understand perfectly, now.  Thanks.  Basically, all four setTimeouts() execute essentially simultaneously, they all wait half a second, then they all fire their functions.   Makes sense.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the callbacks too if you need to use 500 ms as a variable for example:

```
var timeout = 500;

setTimeout(function() {
  thisFunc();
  setTimeout(function() {
    thatFunc();
    setTimeout(function() {
      otherFunc();
    }, timeout);
  }, timeout);
}, timeout);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way would be:

```
setTimeout(thisFunc, 500);

function thisFunc () {
    /* ...whatever... */
    setTimeout(thatFunc, 500);
}

function thatFunc () {
    /* ...whatever... */
    setTimeout(otherFunc, 500);
}

function otherFunc () {
    /* ...whatever... */
    setTimeout(finalFunc, 500);
}

function finalFunc () {
    /* ...whatever... */
}
```